# Any alternatives to Intel Smart Response Technology?

Tags: windows, ssd, hybrid-storage

I like the idea of using SSD for disk caching and benchmarks show good performance, but I don't have Z68 chipset and don't want to change my PC. Are there any alternatives not bound to vendor's hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems to be OEM only, but [dataplex seems to be mentioned as one option](http://nvelo.com/products.html) and is bundled with [some drives by ocz](http://www.ocztechnology.com/ocz-synapse-cache-sata-iii-2-5-ssd.html) and [cosair](http://www.corsair.com/pressrelease/corsair-announces-new-line-of-solid-state-cache-drives) among others. This isn't generic and is bundled with SSD models designed specifically for caching, but isn't tied to a specific chipset.

This thread on [hardforums](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1651370) also mentions [fancycache](http://www.romexsoftware.com/en-us/fancy-cache/) which is in beta. Has a metric crapload of use cases mentioned in its documentation- including traditional write caching, and reducing writes through deferred writes to an SSD, and using more than 3.5 gb of ram on windows 32 bit systems. Considering its free at the moment, and not tied to any specific drive its probably closest to what you're looking for.

I haven't tried either of this, since well i have no SSDs, so YMMV compared to whats promised.

Comment: FancyCache doesn't look very useful, as it's cache is not persistent. But Dataplex looks well enough.